# ASP.NET Parent-Child DropDownList Controls with DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

After fixed from previous issue about paren-child dropdownlist, I wanted to make detailsview display result after when child dropdownlist(databasename) is selected. I tried to add control in sqldatasource in detailview, it seem doesn't work and it show blank. I added @Database in SelectCommand on SQLDataSource.
 Here is Parent-Child dropdownlist code,

```
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Select Server:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownServerName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ServerName" DataValueField="ServerName">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ServerName] FROM [tblServer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Select Database:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownDatabase" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="DatabaseName" DataValueField="DatabaseName">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DatabaseName] FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [ServerName] = @ServerName">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownServerName" Name="ServerName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then DetailsView codes,

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="DatabaseName,ServerName,Instance" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServerName" SortExpression="ServerName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList15" runat="server" DataSourceID="servername" DataTextField="ServerName" DataValueField="ServerName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="servername" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ServerName] FROM [tblServer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Instance" HeaderText="Instance" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Instance" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DatabaseName" HeaderText="DatabaseName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DatabaseName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="InstanceOccurence" HeaderText="InstanceOccurence" SortExpression="InstanceOccurence" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OccurenceNormalState" HeaderText="OccurenceNormalState" SortExpression="OccurenceNormalState" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SupportedFuntionalArea" HeaderText="SupportedFuntionalArea" SortExpression="SupportedFuntionalArea" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary_DBA" SortExpression="Primary_DBA">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="userid" DataTextField="UserID" DataValueField="UserID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Primary_DBA") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID] FROM [tblDBA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="userid" DataTextField="UserID" DataValueField="UserID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Primary_DBA") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID] FROM [tblDBA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Primary_DBA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quarter_Close_Vital" HeaderText="Quarter_Close_Vital" SortExpression="Quarter_Close_Vital" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Business_Importance" HeaderText="Business_Importance" SortExpression="Business_Importance" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Application_Number" HeaderText="Application_Number" SortExpression="Application_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Portfolio_Lookup" HeaderText="Portfolio_Lookup" SortExpression="Portfolio_Lookup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkProcess" SortExpression="WorkProcess">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="workprocess" DataTextField="WorkProcess" DataValueField="WorkProcess" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WorkProcess") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workprocess" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkProcess] FROM [tblWorkProcess]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" DataSourceID="workprocess" DataTextField="WorkProcess" DataValueField="WorkProcess" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WorkProcess") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workprocess" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkProcess] FROM [tblWorkProcess]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WorkProcess") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data_Owner_1" HeaderText="Data_Owner_1" SortExpression="Data_Owner_1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data_Owner_2" HeaderText="Data_Owner_2" SortExpression="Data_Owner_2" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TMASGroupNumber" SortExpression="TMASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMAS" DataTextField="TMASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TMASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMAS" DataTextField="TMASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TMASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TMASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TMLASGroupNumber" SortExpression="TMLASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMLAS" DataTextField="TMLASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMLASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TMLASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMLAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMLASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_LAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList11" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMLAS" DataTextField="TMLASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMLASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TMLASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMLAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMLASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_LAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TMLASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IIASGroupNumber" SortExpression="IIASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="IIAS" DataTextField="IIASGroupNumber" DataValueField="IIASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IIASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="IIAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [IIASGroupNumber] FROM [tblII_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" runat="server" DataSourceID="IIAS" DataTextField="IIASGroupNumber" DataValueField="IIASGroupNumber" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IIASGroupNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="IIAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [IIASGroupNumber] FROM [tblII_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IIASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Backup_Nodes" HeaderText="Backup_Nodes" SortExpression="Backup_Nodes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ConnectionString" HeaderText="ConnectionString" SortExpression="ConnectionString" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Role_Based_Security_Doc" HeaderText="Role_Based_Security_Doc" SortExpression="Role_Based_Security_Doc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Alias" HeaderText="Alias" SortExpression="Alias" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Architecture" SortExpression="Architecture">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Architecture") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList13" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Architecture") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Architecture") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Users" HeaderText="Max_Users" SortExpression="Max_Users" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Projected_Growth" HeaderText="Projected_Growth" SortExpression="Projected_Growth" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Storage_Requirements" HeaderText="Storage_Requirements" SortExpression="Storage_Requirements" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" SortExpression="SID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Version") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008 R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2008 R2 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2012 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList14" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Version") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008 R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2008 R2 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2012 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Version") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [DatabaseName] = @original_DatabaseName AND [ServerName] = @original_ServerName AND [Instance] = @original_Instance AND [WorkProcess] = @original_WorkProcess AND [Primary_DBA] = @original_Primary_DBA AND [TMLASGroupNumber] = @original_TMLASGroupNumber AND [TMASGroupNumber] = @original_TMASGroupNumber AND [IIASGroupNumber] = @original_IIASGroupNumber AND (([Architecture] = @original_Architecture) OR ([Architecture] IS NULL AND @original_Architecture IS NULL)) AND (([Version] = @original_Version) OR ([Version] IS NULL AND @original_Version IS NULL)) AND (([Quarter_Close_Vital] = @original_Quarter_Close_Vital) OR ([Quarter_Close_Vital] IS NULL AND @original_Quarter_Close_Vital IS NULL)) AND (([Business_Importance] = @original_Business_Importance) OR ([Business_Importance] IS NULL AND @original_Business_Importance IS NULL)) AND (([Application_Number] = @original_Application_Number) OR ([Application_Number] IS NULL AND @original_Application_Number IS NULL)) AND (([Description] = @original_Description) OR ([Description] IS NULL AND @original_Description IS NULL)) AND (([Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc) OR ([Role_Based_Security_Doc] IS NULL AND @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc IS NULL)) AND (([Max_Users] = @original_Max_Users) OR ([Max_Users] IS NULL AND @original_Max_Users IS NULL)) AND (([Storage_Requirements] = @original_Storage_Requirements) OR ([Storage_Requirements] IS NULL AND @original_Storage_Requirements IS NULL)) AND (([Projected_Growth] = @original_Projected_Growth) OR ([Projected_Growth] IS NULL AND @original_Projected_Growth IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_1] = @original_Data_Owner_1) OR ([Data_Owner_1] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_1 IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_2] = @original_Data_Owner_2) OR ([Data_Owner_2] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_2 IS NULL)) AND (([SID] = @original_SID) OR ([SID] IS NULL AND @original_SID IS NULL)) AND (([Alias] = @original_Alias) OR ([Alias] IS NULL AND @original_Alias IS NULL)) AND (([Backup_Nodes] = @original_Backup_Nodes) OR ([Backup_Nodes] IS NULL AND @original_Backup_Nodes IS NULL)) AND (([Portfolio_Lookup] = @original_Portfolio_Lookup) OR ([Portfolio_Lookup] IS NULL AND @original_Portfolio_Lookup IS NULL)) AND (([Notes] = @original_Notes) OR ([Notes] IS NULL AND @original_Notes IS NULL)) AND (([ConnectionString] = @original_ConnectionString) OR ([ConnectionString] IS NULL AND @original_ConnectionString IS NULL)) AND (([InstanceOccurence] = @original_InstanceOccurence) OR ([InstanceOccurence] IS NULL AND @original_InstanceOccurence IS NULL)) AND (([OccurenceNormalState] = @original_OccurenceNormalState) OR ([OccurenceNormalState] IS NULL AND @original_OccurenceNormalState IS NULL)) AND (([SupportedFuntionalArea] = @original_SupportedFuntionalArea) OR ([SupportedFuntionalArea] IS NULL AND @original_SupportedFuntionalArea IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblDatabase] ([DatabaseName], [ServerName], [WorkProcess], [Primary_DBA], [TMLASGroupNumber], [TMASGroupNumber], [IIASGroupNumber], [Architecture], [Version], [Quarter_Close_Vital], [Business_Importance], [Application_Number], [Description], [Role_Based_Security_Doc], [Max_Users], [Storage_Requirements], [Projected_Growth], [Data_Owner_1], [Data_Owner_2], [SID], [Alias], [Instance], [Backup_Nodes], [Portfolio_Lookup], [Notes], [ConnectionString], [InstanceOccurence], [OccurenceNormalState], [SupportedFuntionalArea]) VALUES (@DatabaseName, @ServerName, @WorkProcess, @Primary_DBA, @TMLASGroupNumber, @TMASGroupNumber, @IIASGroupNumber, @Architecture, @Version, @Quarter_Close_Vital, @Business_Importance, @Application_Number, @Description, @Role_Based_Security_Doc, @Max_Users, @Storage_Requirements, @Projected_Growth, @Data_Owner_1, @Data_Owner_2, @SID, @Alias, @Instance, @Backup_Nodes, @Portfolio_Lookup, @Notes, @ConnectionString, @InstanceOccurence, @OccurenceNormalState, @SupportedFuntionalArea)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [DatabaseName] = @DatabaseName" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblDatabase] SET [WorkProcess] = @WorkProcess, [Primary_DBA] = @Primary_DBA, [TMLASGroupNumber] = @TMLASGroupNumber, [TMASGroupNumber] = @TMASGroupNumber, [IIASGroupNumber] = @IIASGroupNumber, [Architecture] = @Architecture, [Version] = @Version, [Quarter_Close_Vital] = @Quarter_Close_Vital, [Business_Importance] = @Business_Importance, [Application_Number] = @Application_Number, [Description] = @Description, [Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @Role_Based_Security_Doc, [Max_Users] = @Max_Users, [Storage_Requirements] = @Storage_Requirements, [Projected_Growth] = @Projected_Growth, [Data_Owner_1] = @Data_Owner_1, [Data_Owner_2] = @Data_Owner_2, [SID] = @SID, [Alias] = @Alias, [Backup_Nodes] = @Backup_Nodes, [Portfolio_Lookup] = @Portfolio_Lookup, [Notes] = @Notes, [ConnectionString] = @ConnectionString, [InstanceOccurence] = @InstanceOccurence, [OccurenceNormalState] = @OccurenceNormalState, [SupportedFuntionalArea] = @SupportedFuntionalArea WHERE [DatabaseName] = @original_DatabaseName AND [ServerName] = @original_ServerName AND [Instance] = @original_Instance AND [WorkProcess] = @original_WorkProcess AND [Primary_DBA] = @original_Primary_DBA AND [TMLASGroupNumber] = @original_TMLASGroupNumber AND [TMASGroupNumber] = @original_TMASGroupNumber AND [IIASGroupNumber] = @original_IIASGroupNumber AND (([Architecture] = @original_Architecture) OR ([Architecture] IS NULL AND @original_Architecture IS NULL)) AND (([Version] = @original_Version) OR ([Version] IS NULL AND @original_Version IS NULL)) AND (([Quarter_Close_Vital] = @original_Quarter_Close_Vital) OR ([Quarter_Close_Vital] IS NULL AND @original_Quarter_Close_Vital IS NULL)) AND (([Business_Importance] = @original_Business_Importance) OR ([Business_Importance] IS NULL AND @original_Business_Importance IS NULL)) AND (([Application_Number] = @original_Application_Number) OR ([Application_Number] IS NULL AND @original_Application_Number IS NULL)) AND (([Description] = @original_Description) OR ([Description] IS NULL AND @original_Description IS NULL)) AND (([Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc) OR ([Role_Based_Security_Doc] IS NULL AND @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc IS NULL)) AND (([Max_Users] = @original_Max_Users) OR ([Max_Users] IS NULL AND @original_Max_Users IS NULL)) AND (([Storage_Requirements] = @original_Storage_Requirements) OR ([Storage_Requirements] IS NULL AND @original_Storage_Requirements IS NULL)) AND (([Projected_Growth] = @original_Projected_Growth) OR ([Projected_Growth] IS NULL AND @original_Projected_Growth IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_1] = @original_Data_Owner_1) OR ([Data_Owner_1] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_1 IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_2] = @original_Data_Owner_2) OR ([Data_Owner_2] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_2 IS NULL)) AND (([SID] = @original_SID) OR ([SID] IS NULL AND @original_SID IS NULL)) AND (([Alias] = @original_Alias) OR ([Alias] IS NULL AND @original_Alias IS NULL)) AND (([Backup_Nodes] = @original_Backup_Nodes) OR ([Backup_Nodes] IS NULL AND @original_Backup_Nodes IS NULL)) AND (([Portfolio_Lookup] = @original_Portfolio_Lookup) OR ([Portfolio_Lookup] IS NULL AND @original_Portfolio_Lookup IS NULL)) AND (([Notes] = @original_Notes) OR ([Notes] IS NULL AND @original_Notes IS NULL)) AND (([ConnectionString] = @original_ConnectionString) OR ([ConnectionString] IS NULL AND @original_ConnectionString IS NULL)) AND (([InstanceOccurence] = @original_InstanceOccurence) OR ([InstanceOccurence] IS NULL AND @original_InstanceOccurence IS NULL)) AND (([OccurenceNormalState] = @original_OccurenceNormalState) OR ([OccurenceNormalState] IS NULL AND @original_OccurenceNormalState IS NULL)) AND (([SupportedFuntionalArea] = @original_SupportedFuntionalArea) OR ([SupportedFuntionalArea] IS NULL AND @original_SupportedFuntionalArea IS NULL))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownDatabase" Name="DatabaseName" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
        </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="WorkProcess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Primary_DBA" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TMLASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TMASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IIASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Architecture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Quarter_Close_Vital" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Business_Importance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Application_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Role_Based_Security_Doc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Max_Users" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Storage_Requirements" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Projected_Growth" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Owner_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Owner_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Alias" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Backup_Nodes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Portfolio_Lookup" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ConnectionString" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="InstanceOccurence" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OccurenceNormalState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SupportedFuntionalArea" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_DatabaseName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ServerName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Instance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkProcess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Primary_DBA" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMLASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_IIASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Architecture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quarter_Close_Vital" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Business_Importance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Application_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Role_Based_Security_Doc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Max_Users" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Storage_Requirements" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Projected_Growth" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Alias" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Backup_Nodes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Portfolio_Lookup" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ConnectionString" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_InstanceOccurence" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OccurenceNormalState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SupportedFuntionalArea" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I don't see the declaration for sqldatsource1 anywhere. What is it pulling and how is it populated?

Comment: SQLDataSource1 codes is shown right after </asp:DetailsView>. I want DetailsView to be populated all information in database table from selected databasename on second dropdownlist.

Comment: I see it now. Sorry i missed it. It just has a delete command, where is the select command?

Comment: SelectCommand is after DeleteCommand, but it also after OldValuesParameterFormatString. Find the color black texts. The SelectParameters is after UpdateCommand.

Comment: Try swapping autogeneraterows with autogeneratecolumns.

Comment: ok, I switched to autogeneratecolumns = "False". I selected Database1 then I see weird result of detailsview that show 2 detailsview of database1. Both them of different fieldnames order. I just want 1 detailsview result.

Comment: at least you are getting rows now. I am not sure where the mix up with the duplicates and field order is coming from. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing what  you told it to do.

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownServerName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

That is telling the second list to be based on the selection from the first. If you want the lists to be separate from each other, you are going to need to have a list of database names that you can use to populate the database names list that does not depend on the selection of the server name.

EDIT:

It would appear that your syntax is incorrect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter(v=vs.80).aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DatabaseName] FROM [tblDatabase]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownServerName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

should be

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DatabaseName] FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [Servername] = @ServerName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="ServerName" ControlID="DropDownServerName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What I mean is that it should show 1 database on second dropdownlist because I select server name from first dropdownlist that had only 1 database, not more than 1. So Something is missing.

Comment: I see so you need some kind of limiting criteria.

Comment: Another thing I would like to ask about DetailsView will display result after second dropdownlist is selected, I will be edit it in my question

Comment: Code not showing in comment. I would suggest editing your question or creating a followup one.